# How to plot this function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot the region `$x^{p}+y^{p}\le 1$` in the xy-plane. But when I ran commands like this:

```
RegionPlot[x^0.7 + y^0.7 <= 1, {x, -500, 500}, {y, -500, 500}]
```

I always encounter error messages like:

```
LessEqual::nord: Invalid comparison with -91.0952+125.382 I attempted. >>
```

I am confused - how can I make mathematican know I am seeking the region in `R^{2}`, not in `C^{2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plotting range is invalid. You're calculating `(-500)^0.7`, which is a complex number (`-45.5509762 + 62.69554i` to be specific).

Comment: You might suggest using `Re` or `Im` or `Abs`.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid comparison error is actually not the problem here. RegionPlot[] will plot the region where the expression evaluates to True.  The regions where the expression is complex do not evaluate True and regionplot will leave them blank.

The reason you see a fully blank plot is simply that your absolute range is too large. RegionPlot uses a coarse grid by default and misses the small True region all together.

This works (throwing the Invalid comparison as a warning)

```
RegionPlot[TrueQ[( x^0.7 + y^0.7 <= 1)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
             PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

You can surpress the warning:

```
Quiet[RegionPlot[TrueQ[( x^0.7 + y^0.7 <= 1)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
             PlotPoints -> 100], {LessEqual::nord}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RegionPlot[Table[x^i + y^i <= 1, {i,.1,1,.1}], {x,0,1}, {y,0,1}, Evaluated->True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]